# Laravel localization to show the selected flag

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the flag of the selected language.

In my language file, I have the translate of the language:

```
  'english-short' => 'gb',
  'arabic-short' => 'ar',
  'french-short' => 'fr',
  'russian-short' => 'ru',
  'spanish-short' => 'es',
```

and in the header where I have the language switch, I have this code:

```
@if($locale == 'ar')
{{ trans('header.arabic-short') }}
@elseif($locale == 'ru')
{{ trans('header.russian-short') }}
@elseif($locale == 'fr')
{{ trans('header.french-short') }}                              
@elseif($locale == 'sp')
{{ trans('header.spanish-short') }}
@else                          
{{ trans('header.english-short') }}
@endif
```

Now I have this one to show:

```
<span class="flag-icon-1 flag-icon-{{$locale}}"></span>
```

but how can I add the span into the if code?

Now I have double GB (English) on the page.

I have tried this:

```
<span class="flag-icon-1 flag-icon-@if($locale == 'ar')
    {{ trans('header.arabic-short') }}
    @elseif($locale == 'ru')
    {{ trans('header.russian-short') }}
    @elseif($locale == 'fr')
    {{ trans('header.french-short') }}                              
    @elseif($locale == 'sp')
    {{ trans('header.spanish-short') }}
    @else                          
    {{ trans('header.english-short') }}
@endif
</span>
```

With no luck.

**UPDATE**

I have in `commoncontroller.php`:

```
public function lang() {
         $locale = session()->get('locale');
        if($locale){
             return $locale;
           }else{
             return $locale = 'en';
        }
}
```

And when I select the specific language I want to have:

```
<a href="{{url('lang/en')}}">
    <span class="flag-icon-1 flag-icon-en"></span>
    <span class="name">English</span>
</a>
```

As I said, I see 2 languages now, I only want to see the one with the flags.

[image]

And it´s the @if($locale == 'ar') that show the GB text.

Comment: how about you create a function or blade directive to do this for you?

Comment: how do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Conditional Classes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#conditional-classes) for if you want:

```php
<span @class([
    'flag-icon-1',
    'flag-icon-' . trans('header.arabic-short') => $locale == 'ar',
    'flag-icon-' . trans('header.russian-short') => $locale == 'ru',
    'flag-icon-' . trans('header.french-short') => $locale == 'fr',
    'flag-icon-' . trans('header.spanish-short') => $locale == 'es',
    'flag-icon-' . trans('header.english-short') => $locale == 'gb',
])>
</span>
```

But I suggest you implement a more efficient way. (You can have it checked with an array or create a custom blade directive)

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing in locale from controller or somewhere?
I have worked with Laravel 8 and 9 mostly not sure if `$locale` is accessible that way.
But, you can get the current locale using:

```
app()->getLocale()
```

Secondly, you need to have a middleware that'll update the app locale when changed. Otherwise, whatever you do locale isn't changing.